# Print one file on multiple network printers (Windows)

Tags: windows, printer

In my office, there are several PCs running Windows. Each of them has its own printer. Is it possible to print a file from my laptop simultaneously on those printers, using IP address/lpt/whatever? In the UNIX world, it's possible by using CUPS.

Answer (score 1):

**To my knowledge this is not possible using default tools.**

You could hack something together using the `print` command in a rather twisted batch file. Check out more about [the print command here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772773%28WS.10%29.aspx).

If you don't want to go down the Batch Script Rabbit Hole, you may want to spring for a third-party application. Examples include:

- ePrint Professionals "[broadcast print](http://www.eprintdriver.com/eprint-broadcastprinting.html)" feature.
- [Print Distributor](http://www.frogmorecs.com/printdistributor)
- [Print Rush](http://www.zfirm.com/products/printrush.shtml)
- [Virtual Port Monitor](http://www.alphatronics.net/AVPMon.html) might be able to capture print jobs sent to one port, and then forward them to multiple other printers.
- I think [Print Manager Plus](http://www.softwareshelf.com/products/) (one of the five bazillion versions, anyway) can perform what you want.

Answer (score 0):

About a million years ago I used this freeware product:
http://www.andtechnologies.com/index.php?q=free-software/multiprinter-port

Runs on Windows, but it says only x86 unfortunately.